# What is the electrical or electronic switch on the picture?

Tags: switches

I have a freezer and its compressor is getting too hot and some switch is turning it off. I found out the scheme and there is a switch with a temperature sign just next to the compressor of the freezer. What kind of switch could it be?

[image]

Comment: Could you post: (1) a less blurred picture (2) bigger picture showing how this switch fits with the rest of the schematic?

Comment: I have only this one. You dont need the rest, since it is a switch turning on and off the compressor at high temperatures. I just need to know the general name of these kind of switches.

Comment: While the rest of the schematic might not be needed to determine the type of switch, I find it a bit presumptuous to ask for help then pronounce "You don't need the rest." What if another component, not shown, modifies an important value for the switch? If you are certain that no other information is necessary, then that knowledge should be imparted in the question. I have seen other cases where persons asking questions omitted important details and were led astray because of it.

Comment: The question is clearly asking to identify a schematic/diagram symbol. It's tangentially related to "appliance repair" in that it's a schematic for a freezer, but its clearly not in the same category. This doesn't even need to be reworded. It's a simple identification question, not a "x is broken, fix it for me somehow with magic" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commonly referred to as a Thermostat.
[image]

Source: Every single basic mini fridge schematic ever. Most cheap no-frills freezers and fridges have the same wiring. Power, Thermostat, Compressor. With some protection if you are lucky. Take a trip down to a home depot or lowes and check their display minifridges and you will see the same schematic. Same on the two I use right now.

The picture you provide is just an obscure (and obtuse) way of saying thermostat. They could have easily just written it instead.

**To note, that switch turns the compressor on when the thermostat senses the temperature is too high in the fridge. If the compressor is shutting off from getting too hot, that's probably some internal thermal protection or it could be something else in the circuit. The rest of the diagram IS important to see to be sure.**

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a thermal switch of some sort, probably a bimetallic type like this:

[image: 1] [image: 2]

If you can locate it, you should hopefully find the cutoff temperature marked on the casing. Failing this, and also to confirm it's working correctly if there is a marking, you can always do a test with a controlled heat source and a multimeter, gradually raising the temperature until the switch changes state (e.g. for a normally closed switches open) I have done this a few times to check thermal switches in our washing machine.